# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in mongodb testing with postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am testing my api with postman and it is giving me the error in the title. The code is correct as I am following from a tutorial on youtube. I am attaching the controller code for mongo.When i am sending the post request with the information I am getting an empty message asthe response in the response section of postman. I am getting this error-
[image]

menu controller code-

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Menu from "../model/Menu";
import User from "../model/User";

export const getMenu=async(req,res,next)=>{
    let menus;
    try{
        menus=await Menu.find().populate('user');
    }catch(err){
        return console.log(err)
    }
    if(!menus){
        return res.status(404).json({message:"no menu found"});

    }
    return res.status(200).json({menus})

}

export const addMenu=async(req,res,next)=>{
    const {title,price,image,category,user}=req.body;
    let existingUser;
    try{
        existingUser=await User.findById(user);
    }catch(err){
        return console.log(err)
    }
    if(!existingUser){
        return res.status(400).json({message:"Unabel to find user by this id"})
    }
    const menu= new Menu({
        title,
        price,
        image,
        category,
        user,
    });
    try{
       const session=await mongoose.startSession();
       session.startTransaction();
       await menu.save({session});
       existingUser.menus.push(menu);
       await existingUser.save({session})
       await session.commitTransaction();
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({message:err});
        
        
    }
    return res.status(200).json({menu})
};
```

User Schema declaration-

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema=new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength:6
    },
     orders:[{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,ref:"Menu",required:true}],
})

export default mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

menu schema declration-

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

    const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

    const menuSchema=new Schema({
        title:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        },
        price:{
            type:Number,
            required:true,
        },
        image:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        },
        category:[{type:String,ref:"Category",required:true}],
        user:{
            type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User",
            required:true,
        },
    });

    export default mongoose.model("Menu",menuSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your menu controller, you have the line:

```
existingUser.menus.push(menu);
```

However, in your userSchema, there is no `menus` property:

```
const userSchema=new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength:6
    },
     orders:[{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,ref:"Menu",required:true}],
})
```

That is why you get this error, because `existingUser.menus` does not exist and thus is `undefined`. From your code, it seems that what you need to do is to push the Menu `_id` into the `orders` property instead, like this:

```
existingUser.orders.push(menu._id);
```